# Different Discounts for Different Quantities

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, rules

What would be the step by step to make it so certain sku's are 5% for quantities 2-4, 10% for quantities of 5-8?

I've tried 'contains', 'is one of', 'is' 2,3,4

If I only have 1 in cart, it gives the 5%

If I have 5 it isn't 'bumping' up to the 10% but instead continuing with 5% for all 5 instead of 10% for all 5 in cart

Comment: What is the context of this? What language? How is the data being handled?

Comment: Oh shoot, guess I should have mentioned that! It is Magento, when using the shopping cart rules

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 rules one for 5 percent for 2-4 (see image below), the other for 10 for 5-8. You can also use Max Qty Discount field on the second rule and set it to 8 so that a customer who buys 9 will still get a 10% off of the first 8.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I tried the above, ran a test run and it appears that when adding 6 to the cart, it is 'adding' both discounts together making it almost 15%

Comment: When you are setting up the second rule, are you saying equals or greater than 5 AND equals or less than 8 ? That should exclude the 2-4 rule out of the equation.

Comment: If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
 
Quantity in cart  equals or greater than  5  
Quantity in cart  equals or less than  8

Comment: Also would like to add that the rules I'm trying to add is for a configurable product... The product has 126 options, 2 x 63, meaning, first option determines which set of 63 to choose from. The tier prices I've set up work only if 1 of the 63 options, 2 or more are placed... if 2 are placed that are different, the tier nor the shopping cart price rules do not work. Is there an extension that inhances the default that is installed?

Comment: that would be a separate question you have to create in order for people to find and answer. I do not have much experience with custom options/bundled products unfortunately.